# Slow "lookup" time for Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, rmi

I've created a test EJB3 application running on GlassFish Opensource Edition.

I'm connecting to GlassFish from the same host (both the client and the application server are running on 'localhost').

I fetch a remote (stateful) object using InitialContext.lookup(), and then I interact with it like it were a normal Java object.

The only problem is this single call, that takes **15 seconds**:

```
FooRemoteService foors = (FooRemoteService) 
    context.lookup("java:global/FooApp/FooService!test.FooRemoteService");
```

I understand that there has to be some kind of "handshaking" and "initialization", but this is *so darn slow*.

The rest of the interaction (several remote invocations with many serialized object being exchanged) takes only about 0.1 seconds!

How can I find out the reason why it takes so long?

Comment: Well it's instantiating the `FooRemoteService` the first time you look it up... Any intensive processing it's doing at its end?

Comment: Not at all... If I "new" it with a local virtual machine it takes some millisecond

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to intanciate your initial context specifying your host ip, because it s possible that you have the same application deployed in different host and the EJB spec search for it around the network

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://ip:1099");
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
```

Best regards.